# Accessing outer class with same name as nested class

Tags: c#, inner-classes

I apologize if there's an answer out there, but I couldn't find any.
I'm currently in the situation shown as below. I expected it to throw an error, but it didn't.
The variable inside 'Outer' called 'inner', is an instance of Outer.Inner, the private nested class. I'm wondering how it's possible to access the non-nested Inner instance.
This probably could be done by using different namespaces, but is there any other way?

```
public class Outer {
    private Inner inner = new Inner(); // This is the Outer.Inner class

    private class Inner { }
}

public class Inner { }
```

Comment: Why do they have to have the same name after all ?

Comment: That's another solution besides placing them in different namespaces, but I'm just wondering if it's possible

Comment: I agree with Arthur that you should avoid situations like that like the plague. That said, you can use the full type name including the namespace to refer to the "outer" `Inner` class (my head hurts), like `WhateverYourNamespace.Inner`. Or, if the "outer" `Inner` class is not within a namespace, you could use `global::Inner`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to wrap it in namespaces you can use `global::` to refer to types inside the global namespace:

```
public class Outer
{
    private global::Inner inner = new global::Inner(); 
    private class Inner
    {
    }
}

public class Inner
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine.

I used the namespace before the class name.

```
namespace Example
{
    public class Outer
    {
        private Example.Inner inner = new Example.Inner();

        private class Inner { }
    }

    public class Inner { }
}
```